# LED and PN junction diode maximum frequency

Tags: led, diodes, frequency, maximum-ratings, pn-junction

I know that PN junction diodes are not used in RF mixers as they burn out due to high heat emission, for this Schottky diodes are used.

I am working on a project where I will be producing an IF of about 11 MHz from an RF of about 400 MHz. Then I will feed the 11 MHz IF after proper amplification into a PN junction diode and a red LED in series so that the LED turns on whenever there is sufficient IF power, signifying detection of a signal presence.

The LED should as usual stay lit up due to the high portions of the IF signal and in the low portions stay reverse biased. To keep the current within limits of the LED I will ensure the required resistance.

Is there any possibility of the LED and the PN junction diode burning out at 11 MHz?

Some other questions.

- Why does the PN junction diode burn at RF frequencies (well within VHF and upwards?)
- Up to what frequencies can a PN junction diode and an LED (keeping in mind the various colors) work fine without burning?

Comment: *I have known that PN junction diodes are not used in RF mixers as they burn out due to high heat emission, for this schottky diodes are used.* Huh? That doesn't sound right as stated. There might be some cases where it's true. Where does your statement come from?

Comment: Ditto - there is nothing specific about a pn junction that should cause this. Name the specific part maybe?

Comment: Consider that your I.F. **amplifier** block has characteristics like **input impedance**, **gain**, **output impedance**, and **saturation point**. It will saturate when output signal reaches a voltage or current limit depending on supply voltage and bias current. You can design this amplifier so that when saturated, it cannot deliver enough current to the LED detector to burn it out (perhaps 20mA). Even if its input signal grows larger, amplifier saturation saves the LED.

Comment: So I guess from what you guys are implying, and from what I have analyzed, the LED should stay lit at the 11 MHz IF bright enough to be visible and should not, as I have understood, burn out due to heat emission due to a relatively high frequency.

Comment: *Is there any possibility of the LED and the PN junction diode burning out at 11 MHz?* Yes, if you apply more power that the devices can handle, they can get damaged. This is unrelated to 11 MHz. From your question it looks like you could do with more studying on the subject of mixing signals as it looks to me that you don't understand how the things that you want to do are supposed to work. You mention several things that are simply **not true**.

Answer (score 0):

PN junctions designed for higher current will have higher capacitance , which at RF frequencies makes  the bipolar characteristics weaker with rising frequency. It also lowers the AC impedance at Vdc from junction capacitance and current is limited by the driver impedance.

Thus low junction capacitance is a desirable feature for RF diodes. Specs range for C with higher reverse voltage yielding lower values, tests at 0V is std @ 1MHz or 100 MHz.  Higher voltage diodes tend also have lower pF as well as Schottky and PIN diodes.

Comment: I know the capacitance issue. But 11 MHz is not high enough for the capacitance to be an issue. I was slightly concerned about the heat as I had read somewhere that schottky diodes are used in RF mixers, due to higher switching speeds (lower capacitances) and because PN diodes burn out at RF. But, as it appears, 11 MHz would not be a problem for heat anyways.

Comment: A PN might burn out if the impedance was low (50) and power exceeded Vf in shunt with resulting excess voltage^2 /Rs above 0.7V

Comment: What I am more concerned about now is the rise and fall time of the LED. I downloaded a datasheet of a red LED and there the rise and fall times are mentioned 50 ns each (10→90% 90→10%). At 11 MHz I get a high time of 45 ns and a low time of 45 ns. As per my analysis, this should still keep the LED on, giving a luminance of at least 30%. Which should be bright enough to be at least visible. What say you?

Comment: Yeah a capacitance high enough might start to shunt the diode causing a current high enough to burn it. But anyways a resistor in series might have solved the issue, so not sure.

Comment: If you sort a vendor’s diode list, you will find pF ranging from <1 pF @ 0V to >10nF with high current diodes.